# Assign a default name if the cell value is null

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a booking form, shown.
I also have a template form, hidden.

This script is assigned to a button to create completed bookings by copying the booking form data to a copy of the template and again hides the template and clears the booking form.

The name of the newly created completed booking sheet is pulled from cell C7.

I need to write an argument to assign a default name if the cell value is null.

```
function EXPORT() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sti = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

var sta = ss.getSheetByName('Booking Confirmation');

var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getValue();

sti.showSheet();

sti.copyTo(ss).setName(ti);

sti.hideSheet();



var stc = ss.getSheetByName(ti);

var source = sta.getRange('A5:C23');

var dest = stc.getRange('A5:C23');

source.copyTo (dest, {contentsOnly: true});



sta.getRange('C5:C5').clearContent();

sta.getRange('C7:C10').clearContent();

sta.getRange('C12:C19').clearContent();

sta.getRange('C21:C23').clearContent();


}​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a default value with this pattern:

`var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getDisplayValue() || 'default value';`

Your function will error out in the event a sheet name is already in use. To guard against that, use a `try-catch` block, like this:

```
function exportSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  const bookingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Booking Confirmation');
  const targetSheetName = bookingSheet.getRange('C7').getDisplayValue() || 'Booking';
  const targetSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(ss);
  try {
    targetSheet.setName(targetSheetName);
  } catch (error) {
    const timestampString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), ' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    targetSheet.setName(targetSheetName + timestampString);
  }
  const sourceData = bookingSheet.getRange('A5:C23');
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange('A5');
  sourceData.copyTo(targetRange, { contentsOnly: true });
  bookingSheet
    .getRangeList(['C5', 'C7:C10', 'C12:C19', 'C21:C23'])
    .clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getValue();
```

by

```
var ti = (() => {
  let value = sta.getRange('C7').getValue();
  return value === '' ? 'add here the default value' : value;
})();
```

The above uses [IIEF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Why not use the simpler `var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getDisplayValue() || 'default value';`? Note that neither the IIEF pattern nor the simpler pattern guard against duplicate sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to modify the code to check if the cell value is null and assign a default name if it is. If the cell value in C7 is null or empty using the `if` statement and the `trim()` method to remove any extra whitespace. If the value is null or empty, it assigns a default name of "Default Name" to the variable `ti`.

```
function EXPORT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sti = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var sta = ss.getSheetByName('Booking Confirmation');
  var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getValue();
  
  if (ti == null || ti.trim() == "") {
    ti = "Default Name"; // set default name if cell value is null or empty
  }
  
  sti.showSheet();
  sti.copyTo(ss).setName(ti);
  sti.hideSheet();
  
  var stc = ss.getSheetByName(ti);
  var source = sta.getRange('A5:C23');
  var dest = stc.getRange('A5:C23');
  source.copyTo(dest, {contentsOnly: true});
  
  sta.getRange('C5:C5').clearContent();
  sta.getRange('C7:C10').clearContent();
  sta.getRange('C12:C19').clearContent();
}
```